# *ngFor is not showing any record

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, webapi

[image]

I have read several answers on stack overflow regarding this issue but I seem not to get a solution

I have simple records in database and I would like to show them using an angular theme .

My code is as below

**table-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDetailService } from './../shared/user-detail.service';


import { UserDetail } from './../shared/user-detail.model';
import { DetailsService } from './../details.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';


//import { UsersService } from '../users.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-list',
  templateUrl: './table-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-list.component.css']
})
export class TableListComponent implements OnInit {
 // users: any;
  //currentUser = null;
  //currentIndex = -1;
  //title = '';



constructor(private service: UserDetailService,private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.retrieveUsers();
    this.service.refreshList();
  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent
   


  ],
  providers: [UserDetailService,
    DetailsService],
  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**user-detail.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDetail } from './user-detail.model';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserDetailService {
  formData:UserDetail;
  list :UserDetail[];
  readonly rootURL = 'http://localhost:19199/api'

  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  refreshList(){

    let url="http://localhost:19199/api/Users"
     this.http.get(url)
     .toPromise().then(res =>this.list =res as UserDetail[]);


       }
       array = [
        {
          guid: '900ea552-ef68-42cc-b6a6-b8c4dff10fb7',
          age: 32,
          name: 'Powers Schneider',
        },
        {
          guid: '880381d3-8dca-4aed-b207-b3b4e575a15f',
          age: 25,
          name: 'Adrian Lawrence',
        },
        {
          guid: '87b47684-c465-4c51-8c88-3f1a1aa2671b',
          age: 32,
          name: 'Boyer Stanley',
        },
      ]


}
```

This is the code for html page

**table-list.component.html**

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor='let element of array'>

   <td>{{element.name}}, {{element.age}}</td>
   <!-- <td>{{user.Address}}</td>
   <td>{{user.City}}</td> -->
     </tr>
```

Neither it shows the array data i have defined neither it shows the data from database.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `promise`? use `observable`.

```
refreshList(){
 let url="http://localhost:19199/api/Users"
 return this.http.get(url);
}
```

COmponent:

```
let list = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.service.refreshList().subscribe(response => {this.list = response});
}
```

Html:

```
<tbody *ngIf="list.length > 0">
 <tr *ngFor='let element of list' >
  <td>{{element.name}}, {{element.age}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: I have initialized the list :UserDetail[]; in service and most respectfully in your its in component ,by the way i have tried this way as well but no success

Comment: What do you mean by no success? Are you getting response after api call? To check print it like this `list | json`.

Comment: yes i am getting api response ,i have checked using Postman and as well using direct call in browser

Comment: Dude you have to debug it. Try console.log or print the JSON on html and see what's in there? is it undefined or the data structure is different like that and  provide that here.

Answer (score 0):

You set `this.list =res as UserDetail[]` inside your service,

so you need use the list in `service.list`

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor='let element of service.list'>

   <td>{{element.name}}, {{element.age}}</td>
   <!-- <td>{{user.Address}}</td>
   <td>{{user.City}}</td> -->
     </tr>
```

Comment: let element of service.list    its not working as well

Comment: in your question code, you can use service.array instead of service.list

Comment: yes showing the array but not the list...basically service.list is not working i-e    <tr *ngFor='let user of service.list'>

                            <td>{{user.CompanyName}}</td>
                             <td>{{user.UserName}}</td>
                         
                            <td>

Answer (score 0):

In your html, you tell your *ngFor directive to fetch a list named **array** (which is not a recommended name to use) that is supposed to exist in your component.ts which is not the case, **array** object does not exist in your component.ts, you have to define it.
I would suggest that your service return an observable,

```
 refreshList(){

    let url="http://localhost:19199/api/Users"
     this.http.get(url)
     .pipe(map(res =>res as UserDetail[]));
```

that you intercept in your component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDetailService } from './../shared/user-detail.service';


import { UserDetail } from './../shared/user-detail.model';
import { DetailsService } from './../details.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';


//import { UsersService } from '../users.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-list',
  templateUrl: './table-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-list.component.css']
})
export class TableListComponent implements OnInit {
 // users: any;
  //currentUser = null;
  //currentIndex = -1;
  //title = '';

list$ = this.service.refreshList();

constructor(private service: UserDetailService,private toastr: ToastrService) { }
```

and you use it in your template

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor='let element of list$|async'>

   <td>{{element.name}}, {{element.age}}</td>
   <!-- <td>{{user.Address}}</td>
   <td>{{user.City}}</td> -->
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

After days of work i have found the solution of my issue

```
  refreshList(){
    let url="http://localhost:19199/api/users"
     this.http.get<UserDetail[]>(url).subscribe(res=>{
       this.list = res;
     });
```

Problem was due to the use of .toPromise() function which is of no more use.So above way of fetching record resolved my issue.Thanks to every one who helped me .